# Remove rows having blank value for some column from CSV file using Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I have a CSV file where for a row some value is missing. So if a value is missing then we need to delete that row from the CSV file. I am facing a problem with doing that. Please help me with this.

Comment: Read the file, parse values and write into a new file, ignore the rows where column in empty.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: @YatenderSingh How to ignore rows while inserting into a new file?

Comment: when you are parsing a column then you must be saving into some variable right?
then you can check that all the variables having some value or not, if any variable having empty, null or undefined values then you can just don't write those rows into the new file, just put one if condition before writing into a new file.

Comment: In case you didn't understand, show me some sample CSV file so that I can guide you further.

Comment: @YatenderSingh movie_id url_id ott_id imdb_id movie_title img_url
3931345921060830000 1 1 tt9615020 Natpe Thunai https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/5CL4HpQGiYPD7sv1eQMHOArkSlU.jpg

Comment: movie_id url_id ott_id imdb_id movie_title img_url
3931345921060830000 1 1 tt9615020 Natpe Thunai https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/5CL4HpQGiYPD7sv1eQMHOArkSlU.jpg
@YatenderSingh

Comment: 4635317218084150000 1 1  Dharmaprabhu

Comment: @YatenderSingh in the first case for movie natpe thunai img url is there so I want that movie in my new CSV file and in the second movie Dharmaprabhu I am not getting img_url so that I do not need the second movie in my new CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

We can use a CSV parsing library, such as the excellent [Papa Parse](https://www.papaparse.com/) to parse the data, then we can filter the rows based on the column that we wish to filter on.

For example:

```
const Papa = require('papaparse');

let csvData = `Col1,Col2,Col3\na1,b1,c1\na2,,c2\na3,b3,c3`;

let { data } = Papa.parse(csvData, { header: true });
console.log("Original csv data:");
console.log(csvData);

function filterEmptyValues(data, column) {
    return data.filter(row => row[column]);
}

let filteredData = filterEmptyValues(data, "Col2");
let filteredCsv = Papa.unparse(filteredData);
console.log("\nFiltered csv:")
console.log(filteredCsv);
```

Comment: Thanks and please use node js only not the external script